# Unable to create web view using the in appview package in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create a web view of our website. And for doing this I am using a package in flutter called as `flutter_inappview`. This is the code that I have written, but it doesn't show anything, I see a blank screen on my phone.

sample.dart

```
`import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebView({super.key});

  @override
  _MyWebViewState createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  late InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My WebView"),
      ),
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse("https://google.com"),
        ),
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            // Add your WebView options here
            javaScriptEnabled: true,
            userAgent: 'random',
          ),
        ),
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
        },
        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
          // Handle progress changes
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

I am not sure if I am missing onto any configuration or additional code.

I am expecting to display my website in a webview format in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

To display a website inside the app, I use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but I am not sure about the difference with flutter_inappview